# How can I modify the small icon and title bar fonts in Unity?

Tags: 12.04, display, titlebar, fonts

As you can see in the screenshot, the fonts for the title bar (any window) and for the icons within the file browser (as well as in the navigation pane to the left) are very very small, I have tried to fix this by a number of ways including using MyUnity, but to no avail. Could someone please help me with this as it can render my PC unnavigatable unless I'm sitting right up against it, and even then I struggle. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This may be a longshot, but I've had strange problems in the past that I solved by simply opening the "Appearance" dialog from "Settings", changing the theme, then changing it back.  This somehow synchronized the settings for the theme or something.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately it didn't work though :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe gnome-tweak-tool should have a resolution for this. You can change the font sizes throughout your desktop. It will create an application called 'Advanced Settings'. To get gnome-tweak-tool open up your terminal and:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

When it is finished open up gnome-tweak-tool and go to **Fonts**. Tweak as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a system resolution problem. Hit the Super/Windows key on your keyboard, search "monitors" and open the display settings app. You should be able to personally physically alter your display resolution from there to fit your needs correctly.